# How to get label name from Button?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in `Swift` and I am making a simple calculator where I wan't to detect a button which was pressed and my code is below.

```
 @IBAction func ButtonTapped(TheButton : UIButton){

    println(TheButton.titleLabel.text)
}
```

But It Shows me error like `"UILabel? Does not have a member a named text"`

and it tell me to modify code like this

```
println(TheButton.titleLabel?.text)
```

This Prints `Optional("1")` (1 is my button name)

So anybody can help me why this is happend to me and how can I print my button name without Optional?

Comment: Function names and variable names should start with a lowercase letter. It's a convention that increases readability.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you are sure that `titleLabel` is not `nil`:

```
println(TheButton.titleLabel!.text)
```

else

```
if let text = TheButton.titleLabel?.text {
    println(text)
}
```

Answer (score 18):

More simply, you could just do:

```
let titleValueString = TheButton.currentTitle!
```

If the button's title is not nil, the exclamation point (`!`) will implicitly unwrap the optional (currentTitle without the exclamation point) and you will have a string value for the title of the button in your constant, `titleValueString`

Answer (score 6):

The top answer no longer works. Here is the corrected version for Swift 2.2:

If you are sure that titleLabel is not nil:

```
print(TheButton.titleLabel!.text!)
```

If you are not:

```
if let text = TheButton.titleLabel?.text {
    print(text)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for **Swift 5**
There are many ways to do this but the easiest is just what I mentioned below:

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender:UIButton){
  print(sender.currentTitle!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5: I found this much cleaner

```
@IBAction func ButtonTapped(_ sender : UIButton){       
    guard let btnTxt = sender.titleLabel!.text else{
            return
    }

    print(btnTxt)  

    // now you can make use of this variable
    if btnTxt == "something" {
        .......
    }

}
```